# Best Approach/Algorithm For Finding the Highest Average Subset For a Range Of Events?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, moving-average

Say you have an array of objects representing events over time, i.e.:

```
[
  {
    offset: 1,
    event_value: 22
  },
  {
    offset: 2,
    event_value: 19
  },
  ...etc
]
```

where `offset` refers to the number of minutes that have passed since the start of the event.

There is no guarantee the offsets will be in a predictable interval, i.e. we can have an offset at the 1 minute mark, 2, 3, 5, 8, etc.

If you wanted to find best the 20-minute period with the highest average `event_value`, what would be the best approach to solving this?

(Bear in mind the data is continuous, such as stock prices over time.)

One approach I considered is to loop through the events (from the first one up until the one 20 minutes from the end), calculate the offset 20 minutes on from that point, and see if there is an event there. If there is, calculate the average for that period.

If there isn't an event at that offset, though, then we can either:

1. Find the closest event to that offset and just use that as our range
   (in which case it wouldn't be a perfect 20 minute period), or
2. Predict what the value would have been for that offset using a rise over run calculation

What do you guys think would be the best approach? Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: If an event is alone within a 20-minute interval, then that event *is* the average for that interval. If there are no events within a 20-minute interval, then just ignore that interval.

Comment: The data is continuous, however. Think stock prices over a period of time. We may only have values for discrete offsets, but the stock prices still exist over the periods we do not have calculations for. I probably should have mentioned that in my post. Will edit to make more clear.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for [curve fitting algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve_fitting). Note that doesn't work for stock prices, since they have no underlying mathematical model that makes them predictable (a necessary condition for curve fitting).

Comment: Basically, the task provided was to find the "best 20-minute average" for the value. This is vague enough that I wan't sure how to approach the problem. What would be your approach?